# How to access subsystems from an m file on matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am using matlab and I am trying to change a manual switch from the code in my m.file.

Once i put the switch inside a subsystem it doesn't work. The line of code that works when accessing the switch outside of the subsystem is as follows:

set_param('My_Model/Manual Switch', 'sw', '1')

How can I still achieve this when I put a switch inside a subsystem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the full name to the block, including hierarchy,

```
set_param('My_Model/NameOfYourSubsytem/Manual Switch', 'sw', '1')
```